# Passing multiprocessing.Value object into a ctype function?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I am working with a python function that gets a Value object from python's multiprocessing library passed into it and needs to use a ctype function to modify it. The issue is that I can't find a good way and I'm not sure if it's possible to pass the Value object into the ctype function such that the value will be modified.

My python code looks like this:

```
#main.py
import ctypes, glob
from multiprocessing import Value

libfile = glob.glob('build/*/mod_func*.so')[0]
mylib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)

test_value = Value("i", -99)
mylib.mod_func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]

print(test_value.value)
mylib.mod_func(test_value.value)
print(test_value.value)
```

And the C++ code I am buliding looks like this:

```
//testcode.cpp
extern "C"
void mod_func(int &val)
{
   val = 10;
}
```

I built the C++ code with the command `python setup.py build`, where setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
setup(
   ext_modules=[Extension('mod_func', ['testcode.cpp'],),],
)
```

When I run `main.py`,  the output I get is:

```
-99
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The error is probably caused by me trying to pass `Value.value` to my ctype function, but I'm not sure what else I can do. I can't just use the value returned by the ctype function, because my main python code is going to be run in a Thread and forcibly terminated at some point before the ctype function finishes executing, so I want to iteratively update a value passed into the ctype function that can be viewed when the thread is terminated.

Any ideas?

Comment: `extern "C"` and `void mod_func(int &val)` seems odd. C does not support references.

Comment: Oh so the segfault is likely caused by using a reference and `extern "C"` at the same time? If that's the case, is there anyway to use functionality of the ctype library to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to find the functionality I was looking for by using a callback function.

Updated Python code:

```
#main.py
import ctypes, glob
from multiprocessing import Value

libfile = glob.glob('build/*/mod_func*.so')[0]
mylib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)

test_value = Value("i", -99)
print("Before:", test_value.value)
@ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_int)
def callback(new_val):
   test_value.value = new_val

mylib.mod_func(callback, 10)
print("After:", test_value.value)
```

Updated C++ code:

```
extern "C"
void mod_func(void (*f)(int), int val)
{
   f(val);
}
```

Output:

```
Before: -99
After: 10
```

Comment: Can't you just somehow pass the C function a pointer making it: `void mod_func(int* val)` and then inside of it do `*val = 10;`? Seems like that would have a lot less overhead than a callback…